# Send object with volley

Tags: java, android, node.js, postgresql, android-volley

I have a doubt that is confusing me, i am working with android/nodejs/postgreSQL,
and i was able to send http requests to the server and store the information.

But i was doing that without the considering good practices, that is to have a model associate with the user.

So basicy i get the data from the register form do a simple params.put with the form information and send the data with key/value information.

But now i want to have a User Model and pass the user model trought that params.put and do the same stuff.

Is this considering a good practice?, or should i just forget the User model and do the stuff like this?

here is what i am doing at the moment:

```
 public void register(View view) {

        //get form data
        final String username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
        String email = emailTxt.getText().toString();
        Log.d("email",String.valueOf(isValidEmail(email)));

        if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
            emailTxt.setError("Invalid Email");
        }

        //inicialize a map with pair key value
        final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Add form fields to the map
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        /**
         * Efetua um pedido ao servidor
         *
         * @param URl    url do servidor a aceder
         * @param JSONObject objeto json a ser retornado através do access point
         *
         */
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //TODO verificar o status code da resposta apenas deverá registar login caso seja 200
                        //verifica
                        Log.d("response",response.toString());
                        Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                        i.putExtra("username",username);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String body;
                //get response body and parse with appropriate encoding
                if(error.networkResponse.data!=null) {
                    String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    try {
                        body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
                        Log.d("body",String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                        showToast(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        showToast("You need to connect to the internet!");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("json:","problems decoding jsonObj");
                    }
                }
                //do stuff with the body...
            }


        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

queue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: yes, when you work with a large amount of data approach matters and you are doing it right use model so that handling them becomes easier.

Comment: yes, but how can i pass it trought the volley request

Comment: take a look at answer i am posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope it helps, try implementing in your application**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://foo.com/UserRegistration/volleyRegister.php";

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";


    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;

    private Button buttonRegister;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
            }

        };



           RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == buttonRegister){
                registerUser();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make model class parsable/Serializable.
Step 2: Override toString() in model class.
Step 3: 
     `Map<String,JSONObject> params = new HashMap<>();
        JSONObject object = null;
        try{
            object = new JSONObject(classObject.toString());
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        params.put("key", object);
        JSONObject objectParams = new JSONObject(params);` 
Done!!!